# Change Volume via single command?

Tags: audio, alsa

I need to change my volume on my USB sound card (which is the default card) via the command line. I know `alsamixer` will do that but I need it to be a one line command so I can use it in a python script, e.g., `os.system("volume up 1")`, or something like that. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I haven't used it personally, but if you want to do this programmatically there's [python bindings for alsa lib](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Download).   That should be available as a package on Raspbian -- I don't have a Raspbian pi running right now but I'd guess the package is `pyalsaaudio` (check with `apt-cache search alsa | grep python`).   That will mean reading the API docs a bit, so not as easy as `os.system()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a Bash file with the following code:

   ```
   amixer scontrols
   amixer sset 'Master' 50%
   ```
2. Make the Bash file executable using `chmod +x filename`
3. In Python, use the following:

   ```
   import os
   os.system("directorytobashfile/file")
   ```

Comment: `alsamixer` is a GUI, not a one line command to change volume.

Comment: @PatrickCook I think I got `alsamixer` mixed up with `amixer`

Comment: @PatrickCook added the correct code for `alsamixer`

Comment: `amixer scontrols` just prints the list of controls. And why don't you execute `amixer` directly?

Comment: @CL. Sorry I just do that to make sure I have the right command. I don't execute it directly because this way he can add to the bash file. You could do it directly too!